# how to get backref name in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    addresses = relationship('Address', order_by='Address.id', backref='user')


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

The above code shows a very common one-to-many configuration in SQLAlchemy.

How can I get the `backref` name which is 'user' in the `User` class from a instance of `Address`? How can I know that I have a attribute named 'addresses' in the `User` class which indicates that `User` has many addresses?

I can get all the column information from the `__table__.columns` attribute, but seems like these are stored there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we're trying to encourage use of the [`inspect()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html#sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect) api new in 0.8:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import inspect
>>> inspect(User).attrs.keys()
['addresses', 'id']
>>> User.addresses.property.backref
'user'
```